# how to achieve "swipe up" and call element.requestFullscreen()?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

we have this web app that has a layer element that contain text "swipe up to enter the game", the size of this layer element is equals to the viewport width and height.when the user swipe up (or scroll down) the layer element disappears and the webpage should become fullscreen. I found out that I can use the Fullscreen API, I just need to make the function call for element.requestFullScreen() but this function call return an error if it is not called under a user gesture event. since Scroll down is not a user gesture event is it possible to do this? or are there any workaround to mimic the fullscreen functionality?

Comment: As you have correctly observed, browsers only allow `requestFullscreen` in response to events like `click`, so what you're asking isn't really possible. Besides, it seems like suddenly entering fullscreen mode when scrolling doesn't really yield a pleasant user experience, you might want to rethink what you're looking to do here.

Comment: @aradalvand hello, thanks for your answer. I actually have an element layer that display "swipe up to play the game". and I need to capture the scroll event and check if the user has reach the bottom of the page. that's were i remove the element layer from the dom and call requestFullscree()

Answer (score 1):

`requestFullscreen()` requires user activation, which means it can only be triggered by `keydown`, `mousedown`, `pointerdown`, `pointerup`, or `touchend` and it can't be scripted.

Refs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen

Your best option is on scroll event, you can blackout the page and show a giant button centered in the middle of the screen that says "CLICK TO START" for desktop or "TAP TO START" for tablet/phone. WHen the user interacts with the button you can launch your app fullscreen.

Comment: okay thanks. this gives me knowledge. on how to properly use Fullscreen API. we have this layer element that take all the viewport width and height that says "swipe up to join the game" and it needs to be swipe up thats why I need to capture the scroll event and call requestFullscreen() if the condition meet.

Comment: @normelsss `touchend` might register at the end of the swipe, so you may as well give it a shot. If not, you can always switch the wording to "tap to join the game"